# Python 3.8 unable to find installed modules

Tags: python, linux, pandas, ubuntu, pip

I have Python 3.8 installed along with Pip3.

When I try to install a package with Pip3, it says it is successful but then the package cannot be found by Python. I have posted the terminal output below.

I have been trying for days to resolve this, but cannot find a way to resolve the issue.

```
tobias@tobias-Ideapad-Z570:~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3


tobias@tobias-Ideapad-Z570:~$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3


tobias@tobias-Ideapad-Z570:~$ pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/f7/2adca20a7fa71b6a32f823bbd83992adeceab1d8bf72992bb7a55c69c19a/pandas-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
...
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, numpy, six, python-dateutil, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.19.1 pandas-1.1.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 six-1.15.0


tobias@tobias-Ideapad-Z570:~$ pip3 list
apturl (0.5.2)
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
Brlapi (0.6.6)
certifi (2018.1.18)
...
numpy (1.19.1)
oauth (1.0.1)
olefile (0.45.1)
pandas (1.1.0)
pexpect (4.2.1)
Pillow (5.1.0)
...
xkit (0.0.0)
zope.interface (4.3.2)


tobias@tobias-Ideapad-Z570:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 13:38:56) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I am new to Linux, and a lot of the stuff I saw online regarding this issue is a bit beyond me. Any help would be great.

Comment: could you please check what is the output of `import sys
print(sys.executable)`

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a separate environment for each project

#### Python:

using Python : `python3 -m venv tutorial-env`

Activate the environment : `source tutorial-env/bin/activate`

install the Package : `pip install pandas`

#### Anaconda:

or if you have Anaconda: `conda create -n tutorial-env`

Activate the environment: `conda activate tutorial-env`

install the Package:  `conda install -c anaconda pandas`

and each time you want to work on the same project you just need to activate the environment using `source tutorial-env/bin/activate` or `conda activate tutorial-env`